# LIKE operator with a bindvar pattern which works also for special characters

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such a query:

```sql
WHERE x LIKE $1
```

, where `$1` is a bindvar string built in the backend:

```py
$1 = "%" + PATTERN + "%"
```

Is it possible to build a `LIKE` `PATTERN` in that way that special characters (`%` and `_`) are escaped, so I have the same functionality, but it works for all possible `PATTERN` values.

Comment: I might suggest that you use regular expressions instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to escape the literal `%` and `_` with backslash.  For example, in PHP we might try:

```php
$pattern = "something _10%_ else";
$pattern = preg_replace("/([%_])/", "\\\\$1", $pattern);
echo $pattern;  // something \_10\%\_ else
```